# Complex layout using display flex

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, less

I am trying to achieve the following layout:

[image]

With the following html:

```
<div class="large">
    <div (click)="tap('1')" class="one">1</div>
    <div (click)="tap('4')" class="four">4</div>
    <div (click)="tap('7')" class="seven">7</div>
    <div (click)="tap('0')" class="zero">0</div>
    <div (click)="tap('2')" class="two">2</div>
    <div (click)="tap('5')" class="five">5</div>
    <div (click)="tap('8')" class="eight">8</div>
    <div (click)="tap('3')" class="three">3</div>
    <div (click)="tap('6')" class="six">6</div>
    <div (click)="tap('9')" class="nine">9</div>
    <div (click)="tap('.')" class="separator">{{separator}}</div>
    <div (click)="tap('<')" class="delete"><i class="theme-delete-i"></i></div>
    <div (click)="ok()" class="ok "><span>OK</span></div>
</div>
```

And the following css classes in the LESS:

```
.large {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;

        div {
            display: block;
            margin: 1px;
            text-align: center;
            background: @numpad_keys_background;
            height: @numpad-keys-height;
            line-height: @numpad-keys-height;
            font-size: 1.3em;
            color: @numpad_value_color;
            flex: 1 0 calc(25% - 2px);
        }

        .one {
            order: 1;
        }

        .two {
            order: 2;
        }

        .three {
            order: 3;
        }

        .four {
            order: 5;
        }

        .five {
            order: 6;
        }

        .separator {
            order: 13 !important;
        }

        .six {
            order: 7;
        }

        .seven {
            order: 8;
        }

        .eight {
            order: 9;
        }

        .nine {
            order: 10;
        }

        .zero {
            order: 12;
            flex: 1 0 calc(25% - 2px);
        }

        .delete {
            order: 4;
            height: 2*@numpad-keys-height + 1/16em;

            > span {
                line-height: 2*@numpad-keys-height + 1/16em;
            }
        }

        .ok {
            order: 11;
            height: 2*@numpad-keys-height + 1/16em;

            > span {
                line-height: 2*@numpad-keys-height + 1/16em;
            }
        }
    }
```

but my result is:

[image]

What do i have to change in the flex layout in order to make it work? Please take a note that this view is used on 3 different places in our website so i cant change the html structure. Seems like i cant find a way of using both - column and row difference in the keys (divs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can't do this without additional wrappers. CSS-Grid would be optimal here as it will also allow you to list the HTML elements **in order** rather than trying to rearrange every single one.

```css
.large {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 60px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 60px);
  grid-gap: .25em;
  margin: 1em;
}

.large div {
  background: lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.delete {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2
}

.ok {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 3 / span 2
}

.zero {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2
}
```

```html
<div class="large">
  <div (click)="tap('<')" class="delete">X<i class="theme-delete-i"></i></div>
  <div (click)="tap('1')" class="one">1</div>
  <div (click)="tap('2')" class="two">2</div>
  <div (click)="tap('3')" class="three">3</div>
  <div (click)="tap('4')" class="four">4</div>
  <div (click)="tap('5')" class="five">5</div>
  <div (click)="tap('6')" class="six">6</div>
  <div (click)="tap('7')" class="seven">7</div>
  <div (click)="tap('8')" class="eight">8</div>
  <div (click)="tap('9')" class="nine">9</div>
  <div (click)="tap('0')" class="zero">0</div>
  <div (click)="tap('.')" class="separator">.</div>
  <div (click)="ok()" class="ok "><span>OK</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: with small adjustments i managed to implement this in our company website